# When a $_SESSION variable changes randomly after a page, what is the best way to troubleshoot it?

Tags: php, session, post, mysqli, session-variables

I have been trying to fix this code for the last 4 hours and cannot seem to get it to work. The $_SESSION variables are set when the user log's in (or creates an account) and are destroyed when logging out. Yet, when I submit a certain form, suddenly $_SESSION variables which were working before are throwing an undefined variable error. My apologies for the large amount of content, but in due diligence I've come to the conclusion I cannot find it myself and must ask someone for help.

Relevant code in the order a user's actions call the code.

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';
session_start();


// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
$_SESSION['sessionInitialize'] = false;
// To protect mysqli injection (more detail about mysqli injection)
//$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$mypassword = md5(md5("SaLt".$mypassword."SaLt"));

$query = "SELECT * FROM secure_login.members WHERE username='" . $myusername . "' and password='" . $mypassword . "'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die ($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($result->num_rows == 1){
        initializeSessionVariables();
        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "acct.php"
        $_SESSION['currentUser']=$_POST['myusername']; 
        //$_SESSION['mypassword']=$_POST['mypassword']; 
        header("location:myAcct.php");
        }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        header("location:index.php");
        }

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

The function for initializing relevant session variables for the user.

```
function initializeSessionVariables(){

    $_SESSION['currentUser'] = $_SESSION['currentUser'];
    $_SESSION['currentUserAcctId'] = "";
    $_SESSION['currentUserSummonerId'] = "";
    $_SESSION['currentUserLeagues'] = "";
    $_SESSION['currentUserEmail'] = "";
    $_SESSION['currentUserAvatarURL'] = "";
    $_SESSION['currentUserSummName'] = "";
    $_SESSION['currentUserRealName'] = "";
    $_SESSION['currentUserBday'] = "";
    $_SESSION['currentUserSecondEmail'] = "";
}
```

The account page.

```
<?php
    $summonerName=$_SESSION['currentUser'];
    echo "Current User: " . $_SESSION['currentUser'] . "<br>";
    echo "<br>Current User \$summonerName: " . $summonerName; 
    //Create prepared statement.
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `stats`.`summoners` WHERE `summoners`.`name`='" . $summonerName . "'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die ($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    echo "<br>test<br><br>";
    Print_r ($result);
        //Run query if query object returned
        if ($result->num_rows == 0){
            echo "<h1>=0</h1>";
            //Free the result so it can be used in the following functions
            $result->free();
            getSummonerData(); //defined in functions.php
            injectSummonerData(); //defined in functions.php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `stats`.`summoners` WHERE name='" . $summonerName . "'";
            $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die ($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
            //Get associative array for $result
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['currentUserAcctId'] = $row['acctId'];
            //Print data.
            printf ("<h3>Summoner Name: %s\n <br> Summoner Level: %s\n <br> AcctID: %s\n <br> SummonerID: %s</h3>", $row['name'], $row['summonerLevel'], $row['acctId'], $row['summonerId']);
            //Close result object
            //$result->close();
            echo "<br>";
            //Close DB Connection
            $mysqli->close();
        }
        else if($result->num_rows == 1){
            echo "<h1>=1</h1>";
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['currentUserAcctId'] = $row['acctId'];
            printf ("<h3>Summoner Name: %s\n <br> Summoner Level: %s\n <br> AcctID: %s\n <br> SummonerID: %s</h3>", $row['name'], $row['summonerLevel'], $row['acctId'], $row['summonerId']);
            echo "<br><h4>This data is already in the database. Did nothing.</h4>";
        }
    echo "<br>" . $_SESSION['currentUserAcctId'];
?>
```

Profile.php

```
<p>Profile info</p>
            <?php
                displayProfileInformation($_SESSION['currentUser']);
            ?>
```

displayProfileInformation Function

```
function displayProfileInformation($currentUser){
    include 'dbstat_connect.php';
    $query =  "SELECT * FROM `stats`.`userAccount` where `userAccount`.`profName` = '" . $currentUser ."'";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query) or die ($mysqli->error.__LINE__)){
        if ($result->num_rows == 1){
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            echo "User Name: "; if(isset($currentUser)){echo $currentUser . "<br>";}
            echo "Email: "; if(isset($row['email'])){echo $row['email'] . "<br>"; $_SESSION['currentUserEmail'] = $row['email'];}
            echo "Avatar URL: "; if(isset($row['avatarURL'])){echo $row['avatarURL'] . "<br>"; $_SESSION['currentUserAvatarURL'] = $row['avatarURL'];}
            echo "Summoner Name: "; if(isset($row['summName'])){echo $row['summName'] . "<br>"; $_SESSION['currentUserSummName'] = $row['summName'];}
            echo "Real Name: "; if(isset($row['realName'])){echo $row['realName'] . "<br>"; $_SESSION['currentUserRealName'] = $row['realName'];}
            echo "Birthdate: "; if(isset($row['bday'])){echo $row['bday'] . "<br>"; $_SESSION['currentUserBday'] = $row['bday'];}
            echo "Secondary Email: "; if(isset($row['secondEmail'])){echo $row['secondEmail'] . "<br>"; $_SESSION['currentUserSecondEmail'] = $row['secondEmail'];}
            echo "<br>Dafuq yo =1";
        }
        else if ($result->num_rows == 0){
            echo "Dafuq yo =0";
            echo "User Name: " . $currentUser . "<br>";
            echo "Email: <br>";
            echo "Avatar URL: <br>";
            echo "Summoner Name: <br>";
            echo "Real Name: <br>";
            echo "Birthdate: <br>";
            echo "Secondary Email: <br>";
            echo "<h2>Enter what information you like by editing your profile below.</h2><br>";
        }
        else {
            echo "Critical Error: Contact Admin.";
        }


    }
}
```

editProfile.php

```
Edit Profile
        <?php editProfileInformationForm($_SESSION['currentUser']); ?>
```

editProfileInformationForm Function

```
function editProfileInformationForm($currentUser){
    echo "<form action='processEditProfile.php' method='post'>";
        echo "Profile Name: " . $_SESSION['currentUser'] . "<br>";
        echo "Account ID: " . $_SESSION['currentUserAcctId'] . "<br>";
        if (isset($_SESSION['currentUserEmail'])){
            echo "Email: <input name='email' type='text' id='email' value='" . $_SESSION['currentUserEmail'] . "'/><br />";
        }
        else {
            echo "Email: <input name='email' type='text' id='email' value=''/><br />";
        }
        if (isset($_SESSION['currentUserEmail'])){
            echo "Secondary Email: <input name='secEmail' type='text' id='secEmail' value='" . $_SESSION['currentUserSecondEmail'] . "' /><br />";
        }
        else {
            echo "Secondary Email: <input name=secEmail type='text' id=secEmail value=''/><br />";
        }
        if (isset($_SESSION['currentUserEmail'])){
            echo "Real Name: <input name='realName' type='text' id='realName' value='" . $_SESSION['currentUserRealName'] . "' /><br />";
        }
        else {
            echo "Real Name: <input name='realName' type='text' id='realName' value=''/><br />";
        }
        if (isset($_SESSION['currentUserAvatar'])){
            echo "Avatar: <input name='avatar' type='text' id='avatar' value='" . $_SESSION['currentUserAvatarURL'] . "'/><br />";
        }
        else {
            echo "Avatar: <input name='avatar' type='text' id='avatar' value=''/><br />";
        }
        if (isset($_SESSION['currentUserSummName'])){
            echo "Summoner Name: <input name='summName' type='text' id='summName' value='" . $_SESSION['currentUserSummName'] . "'/><br />";
        }
        else {
            echo "Summoner Name: <input name='summName' type='text' id='summName' value=''/><br />";
        }
        if (isset($_SESSION['currentUserBday'])){
            echo "Birthday: <input name='bday' type='text' id='bday' value='" . $_SESSION['currentUserBday'] . "'/><br />";
        }
        else {
            echo "Birthday: <input name='bday' type='text' id='bday' value=''/><br />";
        }
        echo "<small>(Bday Format~ YYYY-MM-DD)<small>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Finally, this is where the error is thrown with the 2 $_SESSION variables. There doesn't seem to be any reason for this, thus why I've come to you all.

```
<?php
include 'dbstat_connect.php';
//include 'functions.php';
//echo $_SESSION['currentUser'] . "<br>";
//If stmt valid, prepare to insert profile info into `userAccount`
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `stats`.`userAccount` values (". $_SESSION['currentUserAcctId'] . ", " 
    . $_SESSION['currentUser'] . ", ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)")){
    //Bind paramaters
    if($stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $_POST['email'], $_POST['avatar'], $_POST['summName'],
        $_POST['realName'], $_POST['bday'], $_POST['secEmail'])){

        //Execute the query. If true, show proof. If false, display error.
        if($stmt->execute()){
            //Show proof of insertion
            echo "<h4>Your data has been inserted.</h4>";
        }
        //Check if stmt returned an error.
        else{
            Print_r ($stmt->get_warnings());
        }
        //Close statement
        $stmt->close();
    }
    //If $stmt statement returns an error, say so
    else if(!$stmt){
        printf ("Error: %s", $mysqli->error);
    }
    //Close DB Connection
    $mysqli->close();
}


echo $_POST['email'];


?>
```

I really hope someone can help me. I've been stuck here for quite some time now.

Comment: I am afraid that there is a little too much code in the question.

Comment: You're certain you can't do a stranger a solid? It is my capstone...and I'm trying to get the system completed by tomorrow. I even axed my other 16 credits for the weekend to get this done. I'd be distraught if Monday came and I was still on this issue.

Comment: I'm assuming that $_SESSION['currentUser'] is referencing a integer... if not you're going to need to quote it in the insert.

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

Seems you forgot to call session_start(); in your last file ;)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM secure_login.members WHERE username='" . $myusername . "' and password='" . $mypassword . "'";
```

this query is btw. unsafe and not protected against mysql-injections.

you should use the following:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM secure_login.members WHERE username='" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($myusername) . "' and password='" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($mypassword) . "'";
```

On $myspassword the escape-function is probably unnecessary because this value is hashed.

Comment: Ah you too! My eyes just wouldn't see it like the letters in the center of a word... Thank you so much for taking the time. And for the other tips! I haven't yet taken the time to prevent SQL-Injection as I am only a few months in to this (php), so the basic functionality of the site has been hard enough. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have

```
session_start();
```

in all your files, related to this situation?

You MUST have it if you want to use $_SESSION variables through these pages.

Comment: don't forget - you must have this line before ANY output to the browser

Comment: ...........................Paul... You and I instantly have a love/hate relationship. Thank you so much :P